# R : how to run a command between every pair in a list

Tags: r, matrix

I have an n x m matrix, say like so:

```
df = 

1 0 2 1  
1 2 3 2  
3 3 1 0  
2 2 2 1  
1 2 3 1
```

I want to run a function on all the columns, such as `myfunct`, which will sum every column, and then sum each pair of columns, self inclusive.

```
16 17 19 13  
17 18 20 14  
19 20 22 16  
13 14 16 10
```

Is there an easy way to apply `myfunct` to a matrix to arrive at the corresponding square matrix? More generally, is there an easy way, if I have a list of N things, to run a bivariate function between all i,j pairs in that list, outputted as a square matrix?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick function:

```
myfun <- function(df){ 
  z <- colSums(df)
  matrix(rowSums(expand.grid(z, z)), ncol = ncol(df))
}
```

It first takes the `colSums` as `z`. Then we use `expand.grid` to take all combinations of `z` to `z` and takes the `rowSums`. The output is coerced to a matrix with the correct number of columns.

```
myfun(df)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   16   17   19   13
[2,]   17   18   20   14
[3,]   19   20   22   16
[4,]   13   14   16   10
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a nice function for what you want to do in general is the Kronecker product (in your case, the Kronecker sum). So we could start by defining the square Kronecker sum:

```
kronsum2 <- function(x) kronecker(x, x, FUN = "+")
```

With this in hand, we can just do:

```
> matrix(kronsum2(colSums(df)), ncol = ncol(df))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   16   17   19   13
[2,]   17   18   20   14
[3,]   19   20   22   16
[4,]   13   14   16   10
```

So if you wanted to write `myfun`, it'd be:

```
myfun <- function(M) matrix(kronsum2(colSums(M)), ncol=ncol(M))
```

And it's faster than `expand.grid` to boot!

```
set.seed(12083)
M <- matrix(runif(1e7),ncol=100)

library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(times=100L,
                 myfun_mikec(M),
                 myfun_jeremy(M))
Unit: milliseconds
            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
  myfun_mikec(M) 8.326119 8.379396 8.514566 8.415031 8.578411  9.559709   100
 myfun_jeremy(M) 8.869437 8.939920 9.058844 8.974743 9.049183 11.425142   100
```